# Is this the right way to code a query to create a new table in postgres in java?

Tags: java, postgresql

String query = "CREATE TABLE \ "EtherMap\".\ table_name\"( feature_name (20));"

Here feature_name is the variable that contains the column name

table_name is the variable that contains the name of the table

Ethermap is the name of the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE EtherMap."+table_name+" ("+ feature_name+" (20))";
```

Comment: Thank you . How do I go in converting this into a query . ALTER TABLE school_point ADD COLUMN feature_name character(20), ADD COLUMN geom int , ADD COLUMN shape character(10);

Comment: Java uses '+' to append strings to variables - So this becomes `"ALTER TABLE "+ school_point +" ADD COLUMN "+ feature_name+" character(20) ..."`  and so on

Answer (score 0):

You need a type for your `feature_name` column, like:

```
"CREATE TABLE EtherMap." + table_name + " (" + feature_name + " VARCHAR(20))"
```